# PHP Sum of Arrays from Search engine

Tags: php

I have a search engine were sample output would be:

```
productA  price:50
productB  price:70
productC  price:30
```

I wanted to get the sum of the prices of the three product and so I tried the code below.

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $adding =array($result['price']);
    echo array_sum($adding);
}
```

When I use the code above, the output shows: `507030` - were it only brings the three prices side by side. the output that I would want should be "150"

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You're printing values within the loop, so you don't get expected results.

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $adding[] = $result['price'];
} 
echo array_sum($adding);
```

Comment: you might also want to intval or type cast the `$result['price']`. For the rest I agree.

Comment: @Luceos no, there is no need. `array_sum` will convert strings to numbers.

Comment: Ok cool. First answer (other one removed itself) which actually does what it should do :)

Answer (score 1):

You're echoing 50, then 70, then 30 as the array only ever contains one value at a time.

Instead, try: (php >= 5.5.0)

```
echo array_sum(array_column($results, 'price'));
```

or

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $i += $result['price'];
}

echo $i;
```

There's no need to use arrays if you're looping.